# Firebase auth login with facebook, with hotmail

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, firebaseui

My app use the FirebaseUI API, and recently the user that use the login Facebook button of the API, that also has a an email "@hotmail.com", can't log to the app, and in the delegate method of the FUIAuthUI I'm getting the next error:

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1744508f0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    code = 400;
    errors =     (
                {
            domain = global;
            message = "Network error while to fetch USERINFO from FACEBOOK.";
            reason = invalid;
        }
    );
    message = "Network error while to fetch USERINFO from FACEBOOK.";
}}}, error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.}
```

I couldn't figured out what is happening.
The version of the firebase-auth is 3.1.0, firebaseUI 3.0. and ios +9.0

It must be noted that the Android counterpart of the app doesnt have this problem.

Comment: clean the browser cache or change the browser to other

Comment: I didn't try that, but it don't think that the cache is the problem, because it happen in a lot of devices. Still gonna try though.